# VBA pivot swap pivot source in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a loop with pivot tables to create different files from the same source file. Some data is added, then pivoted then the file is saved somewhere under a different name, the file is reused for the next iteration.

As I need the xlDistinctCount function, I am using 
/code

```
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
            ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Pivot_Data")
```

/code
But that also might be the issue. (I am not familiar with setting Ranges for pivot tables.)

Anyways, right now it is saving the Data from the first iteration and then only part of the data is updated.

'''code''''

```
Sheets("Data").Select
                Dim Pivot_Data As Range
                Set Pivot_Data = Range("A3", ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                Workbooks("SourceFile.xlsx").Connections.Add2 _
                    "Pivot_Data", "", _
                    "WORKSHEET; C:\\Path\SourceFile.xlsx]Data" _
                    , "Data!$A$3:$R$1941", 7, True, False
                ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
                    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Pivot_Data"), Version _
                    :=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:= _
                    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6

                Sheets("Pivot").Select
                Cells(1, 1).Select
                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
                    .ColumnGrand = True
                    .HasAutoFormat = True
                    .DisplayErrorString = False
                    .DisplayNullString = True
                    .EnableDrilldown = True
                    .ErrorString = ""
                    .MergeLabels = False
                    .NullString = ""
                    .PageFieldOrder = 2
                    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
                    .PreserveFormatting = True
                    .RowGrand = True
                    .PrintTitles = False
                    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
                    .TotalsAnnotation = True
                    .CompactRowIndent = 1
                    .VisualTotals = False
                    .InGridDropZones = False
                    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
                    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = True
                    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
                    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
                    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
                    .DisplayEmptyRow = False
                    .DisplayEmptyColumn = False
                    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
                    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
                    .DisplayImmediateItems = True
                    .ViewCalculatedMembers = True
                    .FieldListSortAscending = False
                    .ShowValuesRow = False
                    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = True
                    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
                End With
```